# How to add elements from a dictonary of lists in python

Tags: python

given a dictionary of lists

```
vd = {'A': [1,0,1], 'B':[-1,0,1], 'C':[0,1,1]}
```

I want to add the lists element wise. So I want to add first element from list A to first element of list B vice versa
the complexity is that you cannot rely on the labels being A, B, C. It can be anything. second the length of the dictionary is also variable. here it is 3. but it could be 30.

The result i need is a list [0, 1, 3]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In short:

```
>>> map(sum, zip(*vd.values()))
[0, 1, 3]
```

---

## Explanation

Given a dictionary:

```
>>> vd = {'A': [1,0,1], 'B': [-1,0,1], 'C': [0,1,1]}
```

We can [get the values](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.values):

```
>>> values = vd.values()
>>> values
[[1, 0, 1], [-1, 0, 1], [0, 1, 1]]
```

Then [zip](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip) them up:

```
>>> zipped = zip(*values)
>>> zipped
[(1, -1, 0), (0, 0, 1), (1, 1, 1)]
```

Note that `zip` zips up each argument; it doesn't take a list of things to zip up. Therefore, we need the `*` to unpack the list into arguments.

If we had just one list, we could [sum](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sum) them:

```
>>> sum([1, 2, 3])
6
```

However, we have multiple, so we can [map](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#map) over it:

```
>>> map(sum, zipped)
[0, 1, 3]
```

All together:

```
>>> map(sum, zip(*vd.values()))
[0, 1, 3]
```

---

## Extending to an average rather than a sum

This approach is also easily extensible; for example, we could quite easily make it average the elements rather than sum them. To do that, we'd first make an `average` function:

```
def average(numbers):
    # We have to do the float(...) so it doesn't do an integer division.
    # In Python 3, it is not necessary.
    return sum(numbers) / float(len(numbers))
```

Then just replace `sum` with `average`:

```
>>> map(average, zip(*vd.values()))
[0.0, 0.3333, 1.0]
```

Comment: I would lead with the solution, then explain it.

Comment: can you instead of sum find the average.

Comment: @MySchizoBuddy: Sure! I'll add it to my answer; just a minute.

Comment: @icktoofay other options instead of `float` are you can do a cheeky `sum(numbers, 0.0)` or `operator.truediv(numbers, len(numbers))`

Answer (score 9):

So you just want to add up all the values elementwise?

`[sum(l) for l in zip(*vd.values())]`

Comment: i tried this without the *. so the magic is this * in the zip()

Comment: +1 much clearer than the weird map solution that was accepted

Answer (score 1):

```
vd = {'A': [1,0,1], 'B':[-1,0,1], 'C':[0,1,1]}
vd_keys = list(vd.keys())
rt = vd[vd_keys.pop()].copy() # copy otherwise rt and vd[vd_keys.pop()] will get synced
for k in vd_keys:
    for i in range(len(rt)):
        rt[i] += vd[k][i]

print(rt)
```

Comment: Another (more verbose) good solution. You might want to add that it will modify the first element in place, whereas my and nneonneo's solutions won't.

Comment: @icktoofay oh ya ! edited my code so that it does not change `vd`.